# How to disable overshoot in famo.us app?

Tags: famo.us

When reading the famo.us docs in desktop Chrome, I see an overshoot effect when scrolling past the top or bottom of the center container (i.e. below the header). It seems famo.us emulates the overshoot to resemble the native overshoot of iOS apps.

Is there an option (declaratively or programmatically) to disable the overshoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your talking about a Scrollview, you can define pretty much all of the aspects that effect how it handles input. In the options object when creating the ScrollView you can set `edgePeriod = 0`. In physics, the period is the **[time taken for one cycle of vibration](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Period_%28physics%29)**. So this should make sense. More options are documented in the **[docs](http://famo.us/docs/0.2.0/views/Scrollview/)**.

P.S There seem to be a few typos and glitches with the docs generated, I'll file a an issue and see about normalizing it. (*egePeriod*??)